# pdfbox document.save() compilation error

Tags: java, pdfbox

```
package document;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

public class Adding_Pages {

   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

      //Creating PDF document object 
      PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

      for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
         //Creating a blank page 
         PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();

         //Adding the blank page to the document
         document.addPage( blankPage );
      } 

      //Saving the document
      document.save("C:/PdfBox_Examples/my_doc.pdf");
      System.out.println("PDF created");

      //Closing the document
      document.close();

   }  
}
```

i am using above code for practive but my compiler says

> unreported exception COSVisitorException; must be caught or declared
>   to be thrown document.save("mypdf.pdf");

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1):

As the messages says:

Declare the exception in the method Header:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException , COSVisitorException{
```

or add a `try/catch` block

```
try {
//Creating PDF document object 
      PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

      for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
         //Creating a blank page 
         PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();

         //Adding the blank page to the document
         document.addPage( blankPage );
      } 

      //Saving the document
      document.save("C:/PdfBox_Examples/my_doc.pdf");
      System.out.println("PDF created");

      //Closing the document
      document.close();

} catch (COSVisitorException e) {
//handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `throws IOException` to `throws IOException, COSVisitorException`

Answer (score 0):

[Download](https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi) PDFBox 2.0, don't use older versions if you're a beginner. The 2.0 version no longer throws COSVisitorException. And use the examples from the source code download.